# Finding and replacing large amount of keywords in text

Tags: php, dom, text, replace

Say I have a HTML text of about 10,000 words and a list of about 10,000 keywords. I want to find all occurrences of my keywords in the text and replace them with `<span title="a keyword">keyword</span>`. As an additional complication, I do not want to replace key words that already have a `<span>` around them.

What is the best, most efficient way to do this in PHP?

I could obviously build one regex per keyword and run them all sequentially, but that seems like a complexity nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Preg_Replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)
its a very powerful tool to use, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

May be like this? I am not sure though

```
$str          = "this is keyword say this is also keyword say say";
$newtext      = wordwrap($str, 18, "\n", true);
$patterns[0]  = '/keyword/';
$patterns[1]  = '/say/';
$replacements = array();

foreach($patterns as $k=>$v)
{
  $replacements[] = "<span title=\"a ".str_replace("/","",$v)."\">".str_replace("/","",$v)."</span>";
}

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $str);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
str_replace('your_string','keyword','<span title="a keyword">keyword</span>')
```

Comment: Unfortunately he said he doesn't want to replace keywords that already have a span on on them so that won't work. Otherwise you will have spans inside spans.